# Listing log files in some directory and create tar file

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ubuntu, tar

i want to write a shell script in bash syntacs can do
listing all .log files in var/log directory and ask with y/n question for each file to create a tar from that file.
can anyone help me?

```
#!/bin/bash
log='find /var/log -name *.log'
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get only files in `/var/log` (without subdirectories) you can do it on this way:

```
tar cvf tarfile.tar /var/log/*.log
```

if you want also the files in subdirectories you can do it on this way:

```
find /var/log -name *.log|tar cvf tarfile.tar
```

(this may not work if you have space or special symbols in filenames)